# Checking if the page has id attribute assigned before getting its value

Tags: javascript

I've removed jQuery and converted all of my code to raw JS. But now, I came to face an interesting problem.

The problem is, I have PHP generated dynamic pages and I need to get the id attribute from the upload.php file only. Then check if the id's length is empty or not in the JS function.

When I was using jQuery, I'd just do;

```
if ($('#myID').length) {
   // Process stuffs
}
```

It would work without any error. I tried doing something like;

```
let myID = document.getElementById('myID');

if (myID.length) {
   // Process stuffs
}
```

This is fine, but, when users are not in the upload.php page, there is an error **'Cannot read property 'length' of null'**

Can anyone point out the solution for this problem?

Comment: `if(myID && myID.length)`

Comment: Oh my goodness, haha. I never even thought about this. I feel like I just wasted my time creating this post but well, guess it was worth it. Thank you very much!

Comment: `getElementById` returns *a single element* (if anything), there's no point in a `.length` check.

Comment: afaik HTMLElement doesn't have a length property so checking the length is not only pointless, it will break it.. just check `if(myId)...`

Comment: Okay, did not know about this. Thanks for the help.